# Copy files from linux to O365 sharepoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Im my organisation, we are using two factor authentication for O365. I need to connect to sharepoint using python. Is there any way to connect it? And it need to bypass the two factor authentication

Answer (score 0):

Create an Microsoft-Graph application in your company's azure and then connect to sharepoint using the application endpoint of microsoft graph and the given credentials.

[This](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client) is a good package to use